# multiple spinner's simple doubts

Tags: android

Im new to android. i have tried to built an application which has 2 spinner...
i have few doubts to clear before going deep to my application..

please give brief answer to my question...

1. is it possible to have 2 spinners in one view?
2. can i add `setOnItemSelectedListener(this)` for both?
3. if yes, how could i know which option is selected on both the spinners? like `spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();` on both the spinners?

waiting for ur valuable replies. reference materials are also appreciable

Comment: I also got a question: What's the harm in just trying it? Either in a small sample project or in a project under source control that you can revert later in case you are not satisfied with the result.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple spinner's that can be managed by single listener or you can have seperate Listener for each.

For Single Listener you can do something like this,

Set the Listener

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Then you can use `onItemSelected` to get perform the action related to the spinner's.

```
    @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                      int position,long arg3) 
        {
        int id = parent.getId();
        switch (id) 
        {
                case R.id.spinner1:
                // your stuff here
                break;
            case R.id.spinner2:
               // your stuff here
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

Spinner spinner0, spinner1, spinner2;
    TextView textView0, textView1, textView2;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView0 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text0);
    spinner0 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner0);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter0 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, text0);
    adapter0.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner0.setAdapter(adapter0);
    spinner0.setOnItemSelectedListener(onItemSelectedListener0);

    textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, text1);
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
    spinner1.setSelection(0,false); //make sure only one listener is
```

//active in the onCreate method by setting the other listener as false
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(onItemSelectedListener1);

```
    textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    MySpinnerAdapter adapter2 = new MySpinnerAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, obj2);
    //adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
   spinner2.setSelection(0,false);
    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(onItemSelectedListener2);

}

OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedListener0 = new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      //do your stuff spinner0
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
};

OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedListener1 = new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //do your stuff spinner1
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }

};

OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedListener2 = new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //do your stuff spinner2
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }

};
```

}

Comment: Welcome to SO. As much effort obviously has gone into this answer, it might be difficult to get a grasp at if it's just code. It's usual to comment the solution with a few sentences. Please edit your answer and add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If the reference of two spinners are different(which will be , if you are using 2 spinners) , give different IDs for them and you can uniquely identify them, Yes you can set click listener to both of them individually.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() { ... } );
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() { ... } );
```

Answer (score 0):

1. yes
2. yes
3. `spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition()`, `spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition()`

Comment: i did so. and i can now print the value in the second spinner in an alert. but when i try to do it for first, it shows error.
"The application MultiSpinner (process com.myApps) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again [Force close]"