# OnItemSelectedListener on Multiple Spinners not working

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have an Activity with multiple Spinners in it (around 8-9). The code that I am using is as follows:

```
Spinner sp1, sp2, sp3, sp4, sp5;
sp1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
sp2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
sp3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
sp4 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
sp5 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner5);

sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
sp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
sp3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
sp4.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
sp5.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

//Outside onCreate I'm using the following to handle the spinner Item Selected event.

@override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (arg0.getId()) {
    case R.id.spinner1:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case R.id.spinner2:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();         
        break;
    case R.id.spinner3:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case R.id.spinner4:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case R.id.spinner5:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

But the problem is I'm not getting any `Toast` on selecting the item in any of the spinners. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
package com.meta;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.meta.R;

public class SpinnerActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Spinner sp1, sp2, sp3, sp4, sp5;
        sp1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        sp2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        sp3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        sp4 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
        sp5 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner5);

        sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(myListener);
        sp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(myListener);
        sp3.setOnItemSelectedListener(myListener);
        sp4.setOnItemSelectedListener(myListener);
        sp5.setOnItemSelectedListener(myListener);



    }

    OnItemSelectedListener myListener=new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
             switch (arg2) {
                case 1:
                    Toast.makeText(SpinnerActivity.this,"Spinner 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Toast.makeText(SpinnerActivity.this, "Spinner 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();         
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Toast.makeText(SpinnerActivity.this, "Spinner 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Toast.makeText(SpinnerActivity.this,"Spinner 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    Toast.makeText(SpinnerActivity.this, "Spinner 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };



}
```

Comment: @Tony Stark : You have made my day.. worked like a charm ... Many Many Thanks to you... :)

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper what to do in case if the spinners are more than hundreds and you don't know the exact number of them, then how to implement the selection method reply please.

Comment: And these spinners are inside a ListView?

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The int passed into onItemSelected() is the position of the view in the adapter, or in other words the position of the item the user selected. This has nothing to do with which spinner it came from - if you get a position 3 passed in and all spinners have 5 items you still don't know which spinner triggered it. Please see the correct solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150834/multiple-spinners-simple-doubts/8150983#8150983

Answer (score 2):

Reusable onItemSelected method for multiple spinners.

```
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int pos, long id) {
        switch (parent.getId()) {
            case R.id.your_spinner_1_id:
                // get the selected value of spinner 1
                 parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
                break;
            case R.id.your_spinner_2_id:
                // do stuffs with your spinner 2
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
    }
```