# passing variables from within onItemSelctedListener

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I am declaring different variables (temperature_var, size_var, yolk_var)  within `setOnItemSelectedListeners` and I want to pass these variables to another `setOnClickListener` of a button.

The problem is that I can not access the variables (example `temperature_var`) within the `setOnClickListener` and Eclipse therefore tells me to declare the variable locally. I am not sure how I can pass theses Variables within the `onclick`/`OnItemSelectedListeners`. The full code looks like this:

```
package com.example.eggtimer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Call Spinners & Buttons
        Spinner temperature = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerTemperature);
        Spinner size = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerSize);
        Spinner yolk = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerYolk);

        // Register Spinners & Buttons
       temperature.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
       size.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
       yolk.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


        // Call Adapters
         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_temperature = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.temperature));
            // Sets the list template
            adapter_temperature.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_size = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.size));
            // Sets the list template
            adapter_size.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_yolk = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.yolk));
            // Sets the list template
            adapter_yolk.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);        

        // Combine Adapters with Spinners   
        temperature.setAdapter(adapter_temperature);
        size.setAdapter(adapter_size);
        yolk.setAdapter(adapter_yolk);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "It works", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // Call Adapters again ==> I do not know why this is necessary but otherwise the array adapters can not be found within onItemSelected
         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_temperature = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.temperature));
            // Sets the list template
            adapter_temperature.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_size = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.size));
            // Sets the list template
            adapter_size.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_yolk = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.yolk));
            // Sets the list template
            adapter_yolk.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);   

        // Call next button
         Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);

        // Debug Variables
        TextView debug1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewDebug1);
        TextView debug2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewDebug2);
        TextView debug3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewDebug3);

        switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.spinnerSize:

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Spinner selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            break;
        default:
            break;
        }


    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically fields declared final can't be changed after they've been set the first time.

So to be able to fields from within the OnItemSelectedListeners (and other listeners) I'd recommend you chose to let the Activity to implement the OnItemSelectedListener instead of using anonymous methods like you do in your code.

Take a look at this example: http://start-jandroid.blogspot.dk/2011/01/android-spinner-example.html

The guy only uses one Spinner, but as you can see the Spinner gets its ItemSelectedListener set to the activity (this).

Now inside the: onItemSelected listener of the Activity, you should create a switch like so:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
    long id) {
    switch(v.getId) {
    case R.id.mySpinner1:
        // Do stuff when the mySpinner1 has been selected like changing some text on a button like so:
        someString = "myNewString";
        myButton1.setText(someString);
        break;
    case R.id.mySpinner2:
        // Do stuff when the mySpinner2 has been selected like changing some text on another button like so:
        someOtherString = "mybrandNewString";
        myButton2.setText(someOtherString);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, that makes sense. I changed the code but it still does not work. I tested it for the spinner (R.id.spinnerSize) but the text of the button will not change and the Toast will not be called. Do you have any idea why this is not working?

Comment: What happens if you just put a Toast.makeText(this, "Is it working?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() before the switch?

Comment: I just tried that, the toast is not showing. It seems like onItemSelected is not being called for some reason.

Comment: You haven't registered the spinner's listener. Set spinnerName.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

Comment: Thanks for the answer Darwind, I updated the code and registered the spinners. I can now see the Toast "It works" when I select any of the spinners which is good. Nevertheless the switch function does not work. It seems like v.getId() is not getting any results to work with and the second toast "Spinner selected" is not being called. Do you have any ideas why  v.getId() is not working in this case?

Comment: See this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150834/multiple-spinners-simple-doubts - it seems like you need to call the parent.getId() to get the spinner id. I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variables outside the onclick listener if you want to use them outside the listener.

Just put them in the activity and they are accessible to all the different listeners.

On a separate note, if all they are doing is setting text on a view, you could have the activity implement OnItemSelectedListener and have all of them go into the same onItemSelected method. Then you could call `list.getItemAtPosition()` and cast it to a string. It simplifies your code a little.