# same item change listener for multiple spinners

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have 8 spinners:

```
        pl1sp = (Spinner) offersdialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.pl1offer);
        pl2sp = (Spinner) offersdialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.pl2offer);
        pl3sp = (Spinner) offersdialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.pl3offer);
        pl4sp = (Spinner) offersdialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.pl4offer);
```

and

```
        pl1scores = (Spinner) scoresdialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.pl1scores);
        pl2scores = (Spinner) scoresdialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.pl2scores);
        pl3scores = (Spinner) scoresdialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.pl3scores);
        pl4scores = (Spinner) scoresdialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.pl4scores);
```

I need to set them 2 listeners. One for first 4 spinner and one for last 4. I don't want to repeat code like this:

```
pl1sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            checkOffersSum(); // same method for first 4 spinners. for last 4 spinners is checkScoresSum()

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub.

        }

    });
    pl2sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            checkOffersSum();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub.

        }

    });
```

and so on..
    So I need to write listener only twice, first for first 4 spinners and second for last 4 spinners. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

define one listener for first 4 spinner

```
Spinner[] offerspinners = {R.id.pl1offer, R.id.pl2offer, R.id.pl3offer, R.id.pl4offer}; 
for(Spinner offer : offerspinners){
    offersdialoglayout.findViewById(offer).
            setOnItemSelectedListener(offerListener);
}

AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener offerListener = 
    new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch(parent.id){
                case R.id.pl1offer:
                    // offer 1 related code
                    break;
                case R.id.pl2offer:
                    // offer 2 related code
                    break;
            }
            // common code
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub.
        }
    }
```

than define 2nd listener with same code here

```
Spinner[] scorespinners = {R.id.pl1scores, R.id.pl2scores, R.id.pl3scores, R.id.pl4scores}; 
for(Spinner score : scorespinners){
    scoresdialoglayout.findViewById(score).
            setOnItemSelectedListener(scoreListener);
}

AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener scoreListener = 
    new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch(parent.id){
                case R.id.pl1scores:
                    // score 1 related code
                    break;
                case R.id.pl2scores:
                    // score 2 related code
                    break;
            }
            // common code
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can manage multiple spinners using a single listener. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8150983/1306419) answer. It deals with the same issue. Hope it helps.

Comment: It's not working because i'm getting spinners from another layout, like this: 
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
  View offersdialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.offers_dialog, null);

How to set there this view?

Comment: What is the error? So you say that you are unable to use something like: `pl1sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);`?

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Implement `OnItemSelectedListener` in your class and override the unimplemented method `onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2, long arg3)`.
2. use pl1sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(this) and do this for all spinners.
3. Use the overridenmethod `onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2, long arg3)` like this:

   ```
   @Override

   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2, long arg3) {


       int id = view.getId();

       if(id==R.id.pl1offer || id==R.id.pl2offer || id==R.id.pl3offer ||id==R.id.pl4offer){

           // do this
       }

       else{
           //do this
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: replace `int id = view.getId();` with `int id = arg0.getId()`

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create an array containing all your spinners then use a for loop to attach each individual spinner to setItemSelected() method ie

```
Spinner[] spinner = {pl1sp, pl2sp, pl3sp, pl4sp}; 
for(Spinner individualSpinner : spinner){
individualSpinner.etOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int arg2, long arg3) {
           //Custom method here

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub.

    }

});

Spinner[] spinners = {pl1scores, pl2scores, pl3scores, pl4scores}; 
for(Spinner individualSpinner2 : spinner){
individualSpinner.etOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int arg2, long arg3) {
           //Custom method here

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub.

    }

});
```